# vue-resource.common.js:1312 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined(anonymous function) @ vue-resource.common.js:1312

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vue.js

I have googled and googled the solution to this error but I can't see a solution for the exact message I'm getting. i'm still new to modern day javaScript, so please be easy on me and I apologize if this is a bad question.

I am following [this](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vue-step-by-step) video tutorial series and I am trying to leverage Vue-resource.js's AJAX capabilities to fetch data from a database. and when I load my page to fetch the JSON via Vue-resource,I get the above error message when I load the view. Again I am very new to JavaScript, so if the answer is obvious to you I am sorry.

Here is my view:

```
  @extends('app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Recent Games</h1>
<div class="container">
    <games></games>

</div>


   </ul>
    <template id="games-template">
        <ul class="list-group">


                <li class="list-group-item" v-for="game in list">
                    @{{ game.winner_id }}
                    <strong @click="delete(game)">X</strong>
                </li>

    </template>



    <script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.9.3/vue-resource.common.js"></script>
    <script src="games.js"></script>

@endsection
```

And here is my games.js file:

```
Vue.component('games', {
    template: '#games-template',


    data: function () {
        return {

            list: []
        };
    },


    created: function () {
        this.$http.get('api/games', function () {
            console.log(games);
        });


    },
    methods: {
        delete: function (game) {
            this.list.$remove(game)

        }
    }

});

new Vue({
    el: 'body'
});
```

Again I'm still new to JavaScript, so I am sorry if the answer is obvious to you guys. I've looked around and haven't found information that I can understand. (I still haven't gotten to the Browiserify lesson yet on Laracasts). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The `vue-resource.common.js` CDN links to a commonJS module. You'd need to have some sort of module loader in place to get that working (through something like browserify, webpack, require.js, etc).

Easiest solution is to link to the regular javascript instead. Try out this script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.9.3/vue-resource.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for quick solution i visited "https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html"
downloaded the vueJs locally, linked to my script and i'm done.